# How can a column be renamed in results when getting columns from INFORMATION_SCHEMA?

Tags: sql, select

So I have this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getBattingColumnNames
AS

SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Batting' 
AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('playerID','yearID','stint','teamID','lgID', 'G_batting','GIDP','G_old');
GO
```

And it works great.  I get all the column names that I want, in c# I use this to populate a drop down with the column names.  however, one of my column names, "Doub" I would like to change.  So playing around with it I tried:

```
SELECT        COLUMN_NAME.Doub AS 'DB'
FROM            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE        (TABLE_NAME = 'Batting')
```

and a variation of that, and the error is the mulitplart identifier could not be bound.  How can i change that column name in this query?

Comment: When basing user interface elements off of dynamic column names, I strongly suspect the data model does not meet [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), and this ought to be addressed if true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `case` to translate the column name:

```
select  case COLUMN_NAME 
        when 'Doub' then 'DB'
        else COLUMN_NAME 
        end
from    ...
```